# FancyBox iFrame body background-color

Tags: html, css, iframe, fancybox

Hey everyone I'm trying to change the body background-color of the body in the iFrame generated by FancyBox.

It currently looks like this:

[image]

Of course this is not what I want, so this is why I'm trying to change the background color to something like transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set/change background color for element containing iframe and iframe element itself -

```
.fancybox-slide--iframe .fancybox-content,
.fancybox-slide--iframe iframe {
    background: #fff;
}
```

But for iframed page - you have to set it within the page.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the page itself, it's generated by FancyBox

Comment: fancyBox does not generate any page. The script creates markup and iframe element. What are you trying to display inside fancyBox? Can you show your page or any demo?

Answer (score -1):

To change the CSS property of an iFrame , you can use jQuery.

```
$('#yourIframe').load(function(){ 
    $(this).contents().find('body').css({
        background-color: '#333333'
    });
});
```